# Having trouble parsing XML with .Net Core 3

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, xml-deserialization

I haven't had much experience working with XML so forgive me if this is basic stuff. I have a feed that I'm trying to deserialize into an object(s) and some of it work but some doesn't. Here is a sample of the XML in question

```
<rss version ='2.0' xmlns:n='http://something.com/1.0'>
    <group>
        <title>Sample data</title>
        <description>Sample feed description</description>
        <link>https://www.sampledealership.co.uk/index.php/</link>
        <item>
            <n:id>xxx567</n:id>
            <title>Ford Fiesta</title>
            <description>A black Ford Fiesta</description>
        </item>
        <item>
            <n:id>gg567</n:id>
            <title>2019 Camero</title>
            <description>A red Chevrolet Camero</description>
        </item>
    </group>
</rss>
```

Here are my classes

```
public class rss
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "version", Namespace = "")]
    public decimal version { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "group", Namespace = "")]
    public Group group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title", Namespace = "")]
    public string title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description", Namespace = "")]
    public  string description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "link", Namespace = "")]
    public string link { get; set; }

    //[XmlArray("group")]
    //[XmlArrayItem("item", typeof(Item))]
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "item", Namespace = "")]
    private List<Item> item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id", Namespace = "http://something.com/1.0")]
    public string id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "title", Namespace = "")]
    public string title { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "description", Namespace = "")]
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code in my test that is trying to deserialize it.

```
using (var stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(@"Resources/carfeed.xml"))
{
    var root = new XmlRootAttribute();
    root.ElementName = "rss";
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rss), root);
    var car = ((rss) serializer.Deserialize(stream));
};
```

I get all the data contained in the group except for the Items, they are null. I have tried using the XmlArray annotation but still nothing. I'm hoping I have made a spelling mistake somewhere. Anyway, your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Everything works fine. Only need to change access modifier: `private List<Item> item` to `public`.

Comment: Doh! Thanks. I need to get my glasses checked